# How to setup a Ubuntu server 16.04 host machine, for running several virtual machines

Tags: partitioning, virtualization, lvm, ubuntu-server, snapshot

i need some help with setting up my host machine for running virtual servers on ubuntu server.

I have a server with 4x2TB SAS which are in raid6 using raid adapter (dell perc h730p).
The idea is to setup LVM and then use KVM/QEMU, virtlib and virt-manager for setting up and operating the virtual servers.

The problem i have now is, i cant figure out a good way to set up my LVM for this setup.

What i thought of doing was, make the whole disk use LVM during host machine ubuntu installation and then make a 50gb LV partition for it. Then split the rest of the disk into 2 parts, 20GB for seperate /home LV to use across all the virtual servers and rest of the space would to to var/lib which will house all the virtual server images.

Does the above make any sense?

Also, do i need to  make a new LV inside var/lib for each virtual server for snapshots, or how should that be set up?

Answer (score 0):

The best way for you is using two logical volumes (of course if you planning to use only by virtual machines):

```
/ - 50GB
/var - other space
```

KVM, libvirt and virt-manager does not using /home directory, so you no need to create volume for it.

The setting up of LVM is pretty easy, you can start with some introduction article about [LVM](https://serversuit.com/community/technical-tips/view/intro-to-lvm.html).